# How to configure Production build and Development Build vue-cli

Tags: vue.js, npm, webpack, vue-cli

I want to setup a npm script for production build and one for development build. like npm run build for production and npm run buildDev for development.
I have some configurations in each env file like:

ROOT_API: '"url for the production"' and something else in the development env.

The build will be added to the dist folder.
I want the Production Build to be added to the dist folder and the Development Build to be added to a distDev folder.

I have tried to make a copy of the build.js file but without luck.

config/index.js:

```
'use strict'

// see http://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack for documentation.
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  build: {
  env: require('./prod.env'),
  index: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/index.html'),
  assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
  assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
  assetsPublicPath: '/',
  productionSourceMap: true,
  // Gzip off by default as many popular static hosts such as
  // Surge or Netlify already gzip all static assets for you.
  // Before setting to `true`, make sure to:
  // npm install --save-dev compression-webpack-plugin
  productionGzip: false,
  productionGzipExtensions: ['js', 'css'],
  // Run the build command with an extra argument to
  // View the bundle analyzer report after build finishes:
  // `npm run build --report`
  // Set to `true` or `false` to always turn it on or off
  bundleAnalyzerReport: process.env.npm_config_report
 },
 dev: {
  env: require('./dev.env'),
  port: 8080,
  autoOpenBrowser: true,
  assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
  assetsPublicPath: '/',
  proxyTable: {},
  // CSS Sourcemaps off by default because relative paths are 
  "buggy"
  // with this option, according to the CSS-Loader README
  // (https://github.com/webpack/css-loader#sourcemaps)
  // In our experience, they generally work as expected,
  // just be aware of this issue when enabling this option.
  cssSourceMap: false
 }
}
```

config/prod.env.js

```
module.exports = {
  NODE_ENV: '"production"',
  ROOT_API: '"url for production"'
}
```

config/dev.env.js

```
'use strict'

 const merge = require('webpack-merge')
 const prodEnv = require('./prod.env')

 module.exports = merge(prodEnv, {
   NODE_ENV: '"development"',
   ROOT_API: '"url for development"'
 })
```

build/build.js

```
'use strict'

require('./check-versions')()

process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production'

const ora = require('ora')
const rm = require('rimraf')
const path = require('path')
const chalk = require('chalk')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const config = require('../config')
const webpackConfig = require('./webpack.prod.conf')

const spinner = ora('building for production...')
spinner.start()

rm(path.join(config.build.assetsRoot, 
config.build.assetsSubDirectory), err => {
if (err) throw err
  webpack(webpackConfig, function (err, stats) {
  spinner.stop()
  if (err) throw err
  process.stdout.write(stats.toString({
    colors: true,
    modules: false,
    children: false,
    chunks: false,
    chunkModules: false
  }) + '\n\n')

  console.log(chalk.cyan('  Build complete.\n'))
  console.log(chalk.yellow(
    '  Tip: built files are meant to be served over an HTTP 
    server.\n' +
    '  Opening index.html over file:// won\'t work.\n'
   ))
 })
})
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Didn't you try to use `vue.config.js` file to configure Vue build behavior?
You could specify an `outputDir` according to `process.env.NODE_ENV` at `vue.config.js`.

All environment-specific parameters would be set at `.env.development` and `.env.production` files accordingly.

Of course you can modify Webpack config through `vue.config.js` if you need, [examples here](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html).

Output directory parameter changing example [is here](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#outputdir).

At the end, your configuration file will depend only on environment variables and maybe some logic, e.g.:

```js
module.exports = {
  NODE_ENV: process.env.NODE_ENV,
  ROOT_API: process.env.VUE_APP_ROOT_API_URL,
  ANY_PARAM: process.env.VUE_APP_ANY_DOT_ENV_PARAM,
}
```

But remember, that your custom .env params should start with `VUE_APP_` prefix, if you use them at templates.

Answer (score 1):

Add --mode development entry in your package.json file like this: [image]

Comment: Or you can use command "Yarn build --mode development" or "npm build  --mode development" also whatever you are using to build if you dont want to mention in package.json.